# How to monitor 95th percentile web performance?

Tags: performance, web-applications, monitoring, percentile

I want to monitor some performance percentiles (95th, 99th, etc) of a web application. Here's a blogpost about the percentile metric http://blog.catchpoint.com/2010/09/02/web_performance_metrics_best/

It's relatively easy to parse your own access logs and compute the percentile on a minute granularity (or some other time window), but are there any tools that can do this automatically?

Comment: Maybe you should move this to http://serverfault.com/